# bad window path name !toplevel

Tags: python, tkinter, import

I'm trying to make a program where you log in and it takes you to the main menu, but I'm having trouble with the main menu. I thought it could be to do with deleting the root window but nothing I tried worked. This code worked when all of it was in one file but I would prefer them to be in separate files.

```
from tkinter import *

import sys

import sqlite3


def main_menu(root):

    global Main

    if 'normal' == root.state():

        Main = Toplevel()

        Main.title("Main Menu")

        lbl_main = Label(Main, text = "Welcome to the main menu").pack()

        btn_back = Button(Main, text = "Back", command = Back(root)).pack(pady=20, fill = X)

        root.withdraw()


def Back(root):

    Main.destroy()

    if 'normal' != Main.state():

        root.deiconify()
```

These functions are both within a separate file imported into the main file. Everytime I try to run the main file, the log in part works fine but when it comes to loading the main menu, this error code comes up.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__

    return self.func(*args)

  File "C:\Users\*\LOG IN 3.py", line 51, in login

    mainmenu.main_menu(root)

  File "C:\Users\*\mainmenu.py", line 13, in main_menu

    btn_back = Button(Main, text = "Back", command = 
Back(root)).pack(pady=20, fill = X)

  File "C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2369, in __init__

    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'button', cnf, kw)

  File "C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2299, in __init__

    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))

_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!toplevel"
```

If anyone could help me that would be great.
I apologise if this explanation isn't clear. I will try to clear it up with anyone who has questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think what your trying to do in Back is showing the withdrawn root if it is minimized.
you should call state on root, not main because main is already destroyed.

```
def Back(root):
    Main.destroy()
    if 'normal' != root.state():
        root.deiconify()
```

---

ps: In main_menu, you should set the command to a partial method, instead of the result of Back. that will allow Back to be called when the button is clicked instead of when main_menu is drawn

```
from functools import partial
def main_menu(root):
    ...
    if 'normal' == root.state():
        ...
        btn_back = Button(Main, text = "Back", command = partial(Back, root)).pack(pady=20, fill = X)
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. My code now works. Would you be able to explain what the partial method does in general?

Comment: If this answer solves your problem you can accept it. [python docs functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functools.html?highlight=partial#functools.partial). Partial takes a function and any number of arguments and keyword arguments, and returns an object that behaves like a function. When the partial function is called the original function is called with the partial arguments and extended by the arguments at the call site.